# SharePoint 2010: Site Content and Structure copy/move is disabled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to copy (or move) a list (or a library) from one website to another:
From: https ://sp.mydomain.de/Website1
To:   https ://sp.mydomain.de/Website2

When calling Site Content and Structure (https: //sp.mydomain.de/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx) and navigatin to Website1 I can select the list which I want to move.
In the menu action I only can select "delete" - not "copy" or "move" (grayed out).
I am doing this as the site admin (and tried site collection manager etc.)
http://imageshack.com/a/img823/258/oqlj.png

Why are these menu elements not available?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Isn't that MOSS 2007 instead of SharePoint 2010?

Comment: @Abbas: this screen (manage content and structure) has not been updated by Microsoft in the 2010 version :'(. It is SP 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This forumpost**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2bcb1a41-0cb5-4678-99f5-83938875d0c8/move-option-greyed-out-in-site-content-and-structure?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) on Social Technet is about the same problem you are facing and in the answers are several options you can try out. One answer that got my attention stated following:

> The move action is available only for individual items you can't perform  move action for document library or for folder instead of move you can perform that using extension from gary lapointe  http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/stsadm-commands_09.html gl-exportlist command.

This is the last answer on the page. I hope this is of any help!

Comment: This Sir, is absolutely the solution! I am able to move single (or all) elements, but not the list itself (including it's content). Here (http://blog.henryong.com/2008/01/21/how-to-movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-and-preserve-metadata-properties-at-the-same-time/) it is desribed as "1. Create a blank destination List or Document Library. You don’t have to worry about recreating custom fields and whatnot. The move process will do this for you." - That seems not to be correct, because only those columns are copied which exist in the target list. Thanks again!